# JS library for hour/day charts with boolean cells

Tags: library, javascript, data-visualization, graphs

I'm looking for a library that I can use to display graphs with hours on one axis and days on another axis, where the cells are colored based on their value. Here is a draft of what I mean: [image]

Ideally the chart would auto-scale as data for more days are added, and the resolution of the y axis should ideally be adjustable. It's OK if the chart of the library has inversed axises.

Does anyone know about such a library? Or, do you know if there is a term for such charts?

Comment: I don't know of a library but it wouldn't be too hard just to make a html css and JavaScript table then use a library like jquery to manipulate it based on Boolean values

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Schedule for JavaScript](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/schedule/) is a JS based library to consider.

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/hkqcbe5j)

[image: Schedule control showing cell colors]

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Pricing starts at $495" for non-coummuity. I still upvoted though :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see your problem. Any charting library can do that; try [D3Js](https://d3js.org/) or [ChartJs](http://www.chartjs.org/), for instance.

You just have to provide data and labels. In the case of your blue boxes, every charting library I have tried allows you do define a callback function to determine cell content of even CSS styling. That's a single if/else statement.

I really fear that I have misunderstood your problem, as I see no problem. Perhaps you could elaborate? As it stands, it seems to trivial that I agree with @Binvention's comment that you could easily code it yourself.